# Por qué me sale "$(...).owlCarousel is not a function" en mi sitio web?

Tags: javascript, jquery, consola, type

estoy rediseñando mi sitio web y monte un slider horizontal con owlcarousel2. Pueden ver lo que estoy montando en este link https://www.elgatodiego.com/test/. La idea es que cuando se vea en movil aparece el slider. Pero en la consola de chrome me saca el siguiente error:

```
jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (https://www.elgatodiego.com/test/:220:28)
    at l (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:29375)
    at c (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:29677) undefined
```

Cada uno de los css estan debidamente identificados con el **type="text/css"** y lo mismo los javascipt con **type="text/javascript"**. Pero no se que es lo que esta pasando.

¿Que puede ser?

Gracias

Comment: El problema es que no estas enlazando correctamente `owl.carousel.min.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Eso pasa por que creo que has olvidado importar todo el stack de `OwlCarousel` El servidor no ha encontrado ninguno de los archivos en la ruta que has especificado.

Asegurate que estén donde has marcado la ruta a los archivos

Comment: Alberto, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, efectivamente revise la carpeta y estaba mal nombrado la solicitud (estaba usando Mayusculas y minusculas). GRACIAS

Comment: Recuerda marcar como correcta la respuesta para que otra gente pueda guiarse. Saludos